# position:absolute not clearing, still overflowing

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

I have set up a jsfiddle here to show what is occurring:

https://jsfiddle.net/ok87vwnw/

I have used the traditional `clear:both;` method, as well as added redundant commands and divs, as well as used the `overflow:hidden` trick suggested. What I want is for sivContent to stretch to the size of the content inside of it (which will mostly be text). I then also want sivHold to stretch to cover all of THAT.

I would prefer that any fix not require setting any element's height in its css - this is something someone else will be using, and they won't have access to my dropbox, so they will not be able to edit the css every time they add more content. This container needs to be flexible.

I've included my code below.

HTML:

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,700,700italic,400italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div id="sivHold">
<div id="sivGIFHold">
<div id="sivName">TESTING TITLE</div>
</div>

<div id="sivTabs"><div class="sivTab"><input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked><label for="tab-1" id="titleTab1">Threads</label> 
<div class="sivContent">
ACTIVE
[??] Thread Name located in Location
10 Reason
10 Reason
20 Total - Claimed/Unclaimed

INACTIVE
[??] Thread Name located in Location
10 Reason
10 Reason
20 Total - Claimed/Unclaimed

COMPLETED
[??] Thread Name located in Location
10 Reason
10 Reason
20 Total - Claimed/Unclaimed
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
<div class="sivTab">
<input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1"><label for="tab-2" id="titleTab2">Orders</label>   
<div class="sivContent">
ORDER FIVE
[X] Current Order!

ORDER FOUR
[o] [o] [o] [o] [o] Use magic in 5 threads

ORDER THREE
[o] Use magic during a hunt
[o] Train/Be-trained-by another character
[o] Purchase an additional spell

ORDER TWO
[o] Use magic against the Creature Account
[o] Use magic on a character not in your pack
[o] Use magic to help another character
[o] Use magic in 2 additional threads (not included in the above)

ORDER ONE
[o] Demonstrate one Customized Spell
[o] Use magic on 2 characters (not during training)
[o] Help train 2 wolves of a equal/lower order
[o] Use magic in 3 additional threads (not included in the above)
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div> 
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
<div class="sivTab">
<input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1"><label for="tab-3" id="titleTab3">Upgrades</label>
<div class="sivContent">
Total Biscuits Needed: XXXXB
MAGIC
Spell - XXXB

MUTATIONS
Mutation - XXXB

SKILL-TRAITS
Skill-Trait - XXXB

ITEMS
Item - XXXB

ARTIFACTS
Artifact - XXXB

ARMOR
Armor - XXXB

POTIONS
Potion - XXXB

TOKENS
Token - XXXB
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div> 
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</center>
```

CSS:

```css
#sivHold {
background: #272733 url('http://s2.postimg.org/m59xr8lg9/Sivaas_BG.png');
padding:20px;
width:550px;
border:10px solid #1e1e29;
}
#sivGIFHold {
background:url('http://s11.postimg.org/sq8bkw28x/Sivaas_Gif.gif');
height:550px;
width:550px;
text-align:center;
}

#sivPack {
background: rgba(30,30,41, 0.3);
padding:10px;
border-radius:37px;
height:54px;
width:54px;
margin-top:50px;
display:inline-block;
}

#sivName {
font-family:Ubuntu;
font-size:35px;
color:#dac4b3;
margin-top:20px;
letter-spacing:5px;
background: rgba(30,30,41, 0.8);
padding:10px;
border-radius:5px;
display:inline-block;
}

#sivTabs {
  position: relative;   
  clear: both;
  margin-top: -300px;
  padding:5px;
}
.sivTab {
  float: left;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.sivTab label {
  background: rgba(59,59,73,0.5);
  padding: 10px; 
  border:; 
  margin-left: -1px; 
  position: relative;
  left: 1px; 
  font-family:Ubuntu;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.sivTab label:hover {
background: rgba(59,59,73,0.8);
transition: 0.5s;
}

#titleTab1 {
color: #d1d97e;
margin-left:80px;
}
#titleTab2 {
color: #c8ae9a;
}
#titleTab3 {
color: #272733;
}
.sivTab [type=radio] {
  display: none;   
}
.sivContent {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 150px;
  background: #000;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #272733; 
  color: #fff;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:100%;
  clear: both;
}

[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
  background: #3b3b49;
  border-bottom:#;
  z-index: 2;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .sivContent {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Sorry didn't understand about this line "What I want is for sivContent to stretch to the size of the content inside of it (which will mostly be text)". Can you explain more about it? Thanks.

Comment: An absolutely positioned element is taken out of the document flow and so does not affect the elements around it. You will need to **not** use absolute positioning and find an alternative layout method.

Comment: And a number of values in the CSS are `#` instead of a real value.

Comment: @MrLister These are tabbed tables. They need to be position absolute so that those containers stack. The issue is that the black boxes are not stretching to hold the text. Instead, the text is just spilling out the bottom. Clear:both; is a long standing solution to this bug, and has been for years and years now. Except in this specific instance, it is not working with the z-positioning. I am asking to see if anyone knows a work around.

Comment: @HumanLove I want them to function how a div usually does, stretching to hold what is within it. So, if I have a Parent, and the Child within it is 100px tall, then the PARENT will stretch from 0px to 100px, to hold the Child. If I change it so the Child is 200px, then the Parent will stretch to 200px. This is default for div behavior. My divs are not doing this. I need them to do this.

Comment: @SarahGrace That makes it a lot clearer. Sorry for the confusion! In that case, the problem is that .sivContent has `height:100%`, which means the same height as its container.

Comment: @MrLister This works wonderfully! Now, for problem #2.... #sivHold should also wrap around all of that, hopefully stretching to fit the currently active #sivContent div. It's meant to be one whole styled container for this person to display their information on a forum (which allows for html and css in posts but not jquery or jscriptm, hence css only tabs!) –

Comment: @SarahGrace That's impossible with an absolutely positioned sivContainer. If you can't use JavaScript, not even in an `onclick` attribute in the inputs, you will have to think of something else. I may have an idea, hold on.

Comment: I rewrote the answer now, without using `position:absolute`; hope this helps!

Comment: @MrLister it looks exactly as I wanted it to! You've been amazing :) Im taking the two and comparing side by side, hoping to learn something about where I went wrong. I appreciate all of your help, and the time you put in to helping me!

Comment: By the way, I noticed that the background for #sivGIFHold was not OK. I think you meant http://s11.postimg.org/du9sdaqu9/Sivaas_Gif.gif, can that be right?

Comment: @MrLister That was intentional, it was actually a different image, but the contrast on it was just god awful thanks to my having a lose grip on things graphically speaking. It's been changed since then, but thank you for pointing out the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work the way you want to, I had to practically rewrite the whole thing, HTML and CSS. Hope you can use this!

```css
#sivHold {
  background: #272733 url('http://s2.postimg.org/m59xr8lg9/Sivaas_BG.png');
  padding: 20px;
  width: 550px;
  border: 10px solid #1e1e29;
}
#sivGIFHold {
  background: url('http://s11.postimg.org/sq8bkw28x/Sivaas_Gif.gif');
  /*background: url('http://s11.postimg.org/du9sdaqu9/Sivaas_Gif.gif');*/
  height: 550px;
  width: 550px;
  text-align: center;
}
#sivPack {
  background: rgba(30, 30, 41, 0.3);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 37px;
  height: 54px;
  width: 54px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#sivName {
  font-family: Ubuntu;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #dac4b3;
  margin-top: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  background: rgba(30, 30, 41, 0.8);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#sivMenu {
  margin-top: -300px;
  padding-left: 80px;
}
#sivMenu label {
  background: rgba(59, 59, 73, 0.5);
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  left: 1px;
  font-family: Ubuntu;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#sivMenu label:hover {
  background: rgba(59, 59, 73, 0.8);
  transition: 0.5s;
}
#titleTab1 {
  color: #d1d97e;
}
#titleTab2 {
  color: #c8ae9a;
}
#titleTab3 {
  color: #272733;
}
#sivTabs {
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
#sivHold [type='radio'] {
  display: none;
}
.sivTab {
  display: none;
}
.sivContent {
  background: #000;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-top: calc(20px - 1em);
  border: 1px solid #272733;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: pre-line;
  text-align: left;
}
#tab-1:checked ~ #sivTabs .sivTab:first-child,
#tab-2:checked ~ #sivTabs .sivTab:first-child + .sivTab,
#tab-3:checked ~ #sivTabs .sivTab:first-child + .sivTab + .sivTab {
  display: block;
}
#tab-1:checked ~ #sivMenu label[for='tab-1'],
#tab-2:checked ~ #sivMenu label[for='tab-2'],
#tab-3:checked ~ #sivMenu label[for='tab-3'] {
  background: #3b3b49;
}
```

```html
<div id="sivHold">
  <div id="sivGIFHold">
    <div id="sivName">
      <b>SIVAAS &diam; GLAKEL</b><br /><span style="font-size:12px;display:inline-block;">SILVER GLADE CYPRESSMEN</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked="checked"/>
  <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1"/>
  <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1"/>
  <div id="sivMenu">
    <label for="tab-1" id="titleTab1">Threads</label>
    <label for="tab-2" id="titleTab2">Orders</label>
    <label for="tab-3" id="titleTab3">Upgrades</label>
  </div>
  
  <div id="sivTabs">
    <div class="sivTab">
      <div class="sivContent">
        ACTIVE
        [??] Thread Name located in Location
        10 Reason
        10 Reason
        20 Total - Claimed/Unclaimed

        INACTIVE
        [??] Thread Name located in Location
        10 Reason
        10 Reason
        20 Total - Claimed/Unclaimed

        COMPLETED
        [??] Thread Name located in Location
        10 Reason
        10 Reason
        20 Total - Claimed/Unclaimed
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sivTab">
      <div class="sivContent">
        ORDER FIVE
        [X] Current Order!

        ORDER FOUR
        [o] [o] [o] [o] [o] Use magic in 5 threads

        ORDER THREE
        [o] Use magic during a hunt
        [o] Train/Be-trained-by another character
        [o] Purchase an additional spell

        ORDER TWO
        [o] Use magic against the Creature Account
        [o] Use magic on a character not in your pack
        [o] Use magic to help another character
        [o] Use magic in 2 additional threads (not included in the above)

        ORDER ONE
        [o] Demonstrate one Customized Spell
        [o] Use magic on 2 characters (not during training)
        [o] Help train 2 wolves of a equal/lower order
        [o] Use magic in 3 additional threads (not included in the above)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sivTab">
      <div class="sivContent">
        Total Biscuits Needed: XXXXB
        MAGIC
        Spell - XXXB

        MUTATIONS
        Mutation - XXXB

        SKILL-TRAITS
        Skill-Trait - XXXB

        ITEMS
        Item - XXXB

        ARTIFACTS
        Artifact - XXXB

        ARMOR
        Armor - XXXB

        POTIONS
        Potion - XXXB

        TOKENS
        Token - XXXB
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```